# creating a simple XCTestCase, can't find ZeroPush.h which is installed as a CocoaPod

Tags: ios, xctest

I am writing a few XCTests for an app. When I just start editing the AppTests.m, I get an error saying it can't find ZeroPush (which is in AppDelegate.h):

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue
/Users/jt/repos/clients/App/App/AppDelegate.h:10:9: 'ZeroPush.h' file not found
```

but when compiling my app normally, it is able to find it. In my ViewController, it is able to find AFNetworking. How would I fix this?

my AppTests.m

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h" // <- this imports ZeroPush.h 
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface AocWineBarTests : XCTestCase{
@private
  UIApplication       *app;
  ViewController  *viewController;
  AppDelegate     *appDelegate;
  //CalcViewController  *calcViewController;
  //NSView              *calcView;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your app delegate, change:

```
#import "ZeroPush.h"
```

to

```
#import <ZeroPush/ZeroPush.h>
```

I'm making an assumption that the folder it's in is named ZeroPush. Change the folder path to whatever the real path needs to be.

Comment: thx for answer. hmm... wierd, so when I make the change, I still get the same error (but is able to compile). the path seems to be `Pods/ZeroPush/ZeroPush-iOS/ZeroPush.h` but including that won't compile.